# Queries fail when tables are created with pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I create a table with pgAdmin, a table User for exemple. When I make a query on this table I have an error :

```
 SELECT * FROM User

erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « User »
```

There is no problem if i run a query on a table I created with a query...

Is anybody know why ?

Comment: Use lower case names, not a mix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pgAdmin seems to have some problems with case sensitivity: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/438B8BA3.9060209@williamrosmus.com